# Will we not recognize our loved ones?

Tags: rapture

When Christ comes and our loved ones are raptured up, will we have no memory of them. I struggle with the idea that my child won't recognize or remember me or I her.

Comment: Welcome. Could you provide a source/verse which made you say _"we will we have no memory of them"_?

Comment: As Mawia says you're making a few assumptions here that aren't obviously supported. Could you perhaps show us *where* you've found these claims so that we can address them?

Comment: I am struggling with this, too. Why was this closed? Shouldn't the Bible have an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Jesus Christ said that he will come back in the generation of his disciples (Matthew 24, Mark 13, Luke 21). I wrote the details about it here (check my post).

[How will Jesus be recognized at the time of "Second Coming"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/how-will-jesus-be-recognized-at-the-time-of-second-coming)

We have now access to the kingdom of God after we die. After we die, we will be like angels in heaven exactly like Jesus taught Saduccees in Matthew 22. I am sure you will recognize your child just like the disciples recognized Moses and Elijah in transfiguration.